# What is the difference between regular and non-regular tagset of brown corpus

Tags: nlp, corpus

I am working on the Part Of Speech Tagger using HMM bigram model. I am using brown corpus for training. I am not clear about the different tag of brown corpus. Example NN or NN-TL.

Type of question in which i am interested..
1. What is the difference NN and NN-TL.
2. Should I train the trainer with NN and NN-TL as seperate tag or just remove the TL and consider the both same(mean remove the non-regular tag and consider only regular tag)

Answer (score 1):

The `-TL` suffix is used when the word occurs in a title.  For your particular application, simply ignoring this suffix (and similar ones, such as `-HL`) would seem to make sense.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_Corpus#Part-of-speech_tags_used has a succinct summary of these conventions.

Obviously, for any serious use of the corpus, you should read its complete manual thoroughly.

Comment: I have implemented a POS Tagger with HMM bigram model and viterbi algorithm to test it. I have taken all the tags as it is means NN and NN-TL are different tag and also used the combined tag but i am not getting the good result. I am thinking to seperate the regular and non-regular tag like FW,HL,TL are non-regular so i would skip them but i would consider all the combined tag as it is like isn't tag (BEZ*) or  wanna tag(VB+TO). should I also seperate the combined tag or only regular and non-regular....